# Shutterstock api returns Not Found

Tags: shutterstock

I'm using Shutterstock API to load information about my images to my local  app. I'm doing just simple request like https://api.shutterstock.com/v2/images/1334814356. Before it worked fine but now it returns me response {"message":"Not Found"}. Does anyone faced with such problem?

Answer (score 0):

Shutterstock recently started enforcing limitations on what free API accounts can do with the API. One of those limitations is that API search requests with a free account get info about only a subset of their content library, so the images you're looking for must not be in that subset.

Look up your application at https://developers.shutterstock.com/user/me/apps and see what API product it uses. If it's "Free," you've got limited API access as described here:

https://developers.shutterstock.com/documentation/authentication#subscriptions